# Aggregate up to current row without loops in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a dataset with `id`, `event` and `metric` columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','x', 1], 
                  ['a','x',2],  
                  ['b','y',3],  
                  ['a','z',4],  
                  ['a','j',5]], columns = ['id','event','metric'])

   id event metric
0   a   x   1
1   a   x   2
2   b   y   3
3   a   z   4
4   a   j   5
```

I need to group it by `id` and `event` to get `sum`, `mean`, `std`, `min`, `max` aggregations of `metric` that would include not only values for a given "id-event" group, but also `metric` values for **all the previous events** for given `id`. In other words, I need aggregations for all rows up to a given row.

Desired output:

```
   id event sum mean        std       min   max
0   a   j   12  3.000000    1.825742    1   5
1   a   x   3   1.500000    0.707107    1   2
2   a   z   7   2.333333    1.527525    1   4
3   b   y   3   3.000000    NaN         3   3
```

I tried the for-loop approach, when I just filtered my dataframe for each group. But the problem is I have around 20M rows, so it took forever to calculate. I'm trying to solve this **without loops**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `sort_values` on `id` with option `quicksort` to sort on `id` but keep original order on other columns. Next, `groupby` on `id` and `expanding` on `sum, mean, std, min, max`. Finally, `pd.concat` to add `event` columns to final df. `drop_duplicates` to keep only last row of each group `id-event`, and `sort_values` to get the order you desire.

```
df1 = df.sort_values('id', kind='quicksort')
df2 = df1.groupby('id').expanding().metric.agg(['sum', 'mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']).droplevel(1)
df_final = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('id').event, df2], axis=1).reset_index().
              drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'event'], keep='last').
              sort_values(['id', 'event']))

Out[96]:
  id event   sum      mean       std  min  max
3  a     j  12.0  3.000000  1.825742  1.0  5.0
1  a     x   3.0  1.500000  0.707107  1.0  2.0
2  a     z   7.0  2.333333  1.527525  1.0  4.0
4  b     y   3.0  3.000000       NaN  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: The result is perfect except for "a-x" group. Why is it a 4 there? Should be 3, right?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for other aggregations. E.g. for mean (df.groupby('id').cumsum().groupby([t.id, t.event]).metric.mean().reset_index()) for a-j group it gives 12. Should be (1+2+4+5)/4=3

Comment: could you post desired output for the rest of `mean`, `min`, `max`, `std`?

Comment: I added the complete desired output

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `groupby`.

```py
df.groupby(["id", "event"])["metric"].describe()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would give me only the aggregated values for each "id", "event". The tricky part is I need all metric values before this event to be also aggregated. So I think Groupby doesn't solve the problem (at least in this basic form).